# Spyder Icon after installing Anaconda

Tags: installation, anaconda, spyder

I downloaded Anaconda3 and can not see a Spyder icon. Should it come automatically (and is there any difference between windows10 and OSx) and if not, what might be my problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using macOS or Windows?

Comment: I use macOS, but I would be interested in both systems!

Comment: It works well on Windows but on macOS it's not working at the moment. We plan to make it work in the future, but we I don't know when that will exactly happen, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> It works well on Windows but on macOS it's not working at the moment.
>   We plan to make it work in the future, but we I don't know when that
>   will exactly happen, sorry. – Carlos Cordoba Jul 16 at 19:14

Edit: The right icon should be shown in the macOS Dock since Spyder **3.2.3**.